# Adding single quotes to a value of a variable

Tags: python-3.x, string, concatenation

Suppose we have a variable  `foo = "text"` . How would you transform it to  `foo = '"text"'` ? Is there a way of doing this without using the library  `urllib2` ?

**Edit**: Below is a script:

```
def most_common(lst):
    if(len(lst) > 0):
        return max(set(lst), key=lst.count)
    else:
        return 0

test_list = list(df['a'])) # a is a column that can take the the values '"apple"', '"pear"', '"carrot"'

test_list_most = most_common(test_list) # returns "apple"
```

But suppose we want to filter the data frame:

```
df = len(df[df['a'] == test_list_most].index) # length would be 0
```

That is the context for this question and why we want to add the single quotes around the double quotes.

Comment: What is role of `urllib2` for this?

Comment: `foo = "text"` is the 4 letters `t e x t`. You want the six leters `" t e x t "`? How is `foo = '"text"'` not already the answer?

Comment: `>>> foo="'\"test\"'"   
>>> print(foo)    
'"test"'`

Comment: I think the answer is to cleanup the dataframe by stripping those extra quotes from column a: `df['a'] = df['a'].str.slice(1, -1)`. I also wonder whether column a really has those qoutes or whether that's just the `repr` represenation pandas uses when displaying a dataframe. Does `print(df['a'][0])` show the quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the double quotation marks around it: `'"' + foo + '"'`. Or `f'"{foo}"'`, if you prefer format strings.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean by:

```
print(f"'{foo}'")
```

Output:

```
'text'
```

Or:

```
print(f'"{foo}"')
```

Output:

```
"text"
```

Comment: @DYZ It isn't clear of what the OP wants, anyways I posted to possible answers

Comment: @U11-Forward: I want '"text"'

Comment: @timeinception23 - Since quotes are used by python to delimit strings you keep leaving us wondering what you mean by '"text"'. Is it the 6 characters `['"', 't', 'e', 'x', 't', '"']`? If so, then `foo = '"text"'` is already it. What are we trying to solve?

Comment: @tdelaney: If you want to filter a pandas data frame like df = df[df['a'] == foo] where 'a' is some column of df but foo is supposed to be '"text"' instead of "text". Or if foo = "apple", it should be '"apple"'.

Comment: @timeinception23 - or, you could answer my very specific question. How is `foo = '"Text"'` not the right answer? Its how you get the 6 letters you want.

Comment: @tdelaney: Because you don't know in advance what the value of foo is. foo is a variable that can have many values. So that answer is not correct.

Comment: @timeinception23 - Excellent! That's the bit of information that is missing. It appears that you want to surround an incoming variable with double quotes. Perhaps this is code in a function? You could write a small demo script in the question. Its odd that your dataframe has these extra quotes. It may be better to clean that data instead.

Comment: @tdelaney: I added an edit. The data frame was initially a PySpark data frame and I converted it to a pandas data frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the character like this

```
print("'\"Hello World\"'")
```

it'll give the output as

```
print("'\"Hello World\"'")
```

or when you need to assign to a variable

```
foo = "'\"Hello World\"'"
```

hope it answers your question